# Cannot read property map of undefined react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a component that uses an array of filters to make a list. I pass the array as an argument to the function but it returns an error. The array is not null or undefined because it shows the itens if I log to the console.

Console.log returns:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 const List = (filtrosPorTipo) => {
    let filtros = filtrosPorTipo[0]
    let valoresDosFiltros = filtrosPorTipo[1]

    let lista = (
      <List>
        {filtros.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <ListItem
                button
                onClick={() => setOpen({ [item]: !open[item] })}
                key={item}
              >
                <ListItemText primary={item} />
                {open[item] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
              </ListItem>
              <Collapse in={open[item]} timeout='auto'>
                <List component='div' disablePadding>
                  {valoresDosFiltros[index].map((filtro) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        <ListItem key={filtro}>
                          <p>{`${filtro}\n`}</p>
                          <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                            <Checkbox
                              label={filtro}
                              key={filtro.toString()}
                              color='primary'
                              onChange={() => handleChecked(filtro)}
                              checked={checked[filtro]}
                            />
                          </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                        </ListItem>
                        <Divider />
                      </>
                    )
                  })}
                </List>
              </Collapse>
            </>
          )
        })}
      </List>
    )

    return lista
  }
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Try ```filtros && filtros.map()```.

Comment: if add sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) in better for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the component it's trying to render before "filtros" is assigned. It's a common and logical behavior in React.

Try adding a conditional before the .map() call:

```
{filtros ? filtros.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <ListItem
            button
            onClick={() => setOpen({ [item]: !open[item] })}
            key={item}
          >
            <ListItemText primary={item} />
            {open[item] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={open[item]} timeout='auto'>
            <List component='div' disablePadding>
              {valoresDosFiltros[index].map((filtro) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <ListItem key={filtro}>
                      <p>{`${filtro}\n`}</p>
                      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                        <Checkbox
                          label={filtro}
                          key={filtro.toString()}
                          color='primary'
                          onChange={() => handleChecked(filtro)}
                          checked={checked[filtro]}
                        />
                      </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                    </ListItem>
                    <Divider />
                  </>
                )
              })}
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </>
      )
    }) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the values when they are present like so. If you are not planning on displaying a Loading screen in the process of waiting for the data then this would work. Otherwise use a ternary operator like the other answer.

```
{filtros && filtros.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <ListItem
            button
            onClick={() => setOpen({ [item]: !open[item] })}
            key={item}
          >
            <ListItemText primary={item} />
            {open[item] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={open[item]} timeout='auto'>
            <List component='div' disablePadding>
              {valoresDosFiltros[index].map((filtro) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    <ListItem key={filtro}>
                      <p>{`${filtro}\n`}</p>
                      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                        <Checkbox
                          label={filtro}
                          key={filtro.toString()}
                          color='primary'
                          onChange={() => handleChecked(filtro)}
                          checked={checked[filtro]}
                        />
                      </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                    </ListItem>
                    <Divider />
                  </>
                )
              })}
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </>
      )
    })}
```

Answer (score 0):

While rendering the component you have to check data in `filtrosPorTipo`. It has an array value or not. Like below:

```
const List = (filtrosPorTipo) => {
  if (filtrosPorTipo && filtrosPorTipo.length > 0) {
    let filtros = filtrosPorTipo[0]
    let valoresDosFiltros = filtrosPorTipo[1]

    let lista = (
      <List>
        {filtros.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <ListItem
                button
                onClick={() => setOpen({ [item]: !open[item] })}
                key={item}
              >
                <ListItemText primary={item} />
                {open[item] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
              </ListItem>
              <Collapse in={open[item]} timeout='auto'>
                <List component='div' disablePadding>
                  {valoresDosFiltros[index].map((filtro) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        <ListItem key={filtro}>
                          <p>{`${filtro}\n`}</p>
                          <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                            <Checkbox
                              label={filtro}
                              key={filtro.toString()}
                              color='primary'
                              onChange={() => handleChecked(filtro)}
                              checked={checked[filtro]}
                            />
                          </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                        </ListItem>
                        <Divider />
                      </>
                    )
                  })}
                </List>
              </Collapse>
            </>
          )
        })}
      </List>
    )

    return lista
  }
  return 'No data available!'
}
```